# Why can't I pass my 'file' variable to actionPerformed?

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to write a Java GUI that takes a file containing song information, allows the user to edit it, then outputs the new file with the same name. The file pathway is supplied by a run-time parameter, so the user would run the program like:

```
java myProgram myFile
```

This is how I am initializing the file in the main method (I am assuming since the file pathway is input as a run-time parameter, it must be assigned to a variable in the main method. I am not sure if I am correct):

```
public class SongDatabase extends JFrame
{

public SongDatabase(File file) throws IOException
{
    setSize(700, 500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new Panel(file);
    this.add(panel);
}

public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
{
    File file = null;
    if (args.length == 1)
    {
        file = new File(args[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("No source file entered. Create source file (1 for yes 2 for no)?");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = input.nextInt();
        if (choice ==2)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
    }

    JFrame frame = new SongDatabase(file);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Upon selecting an "exit" button in the GUI, the program should take the stored data and output it using the same file pathway (basically overwriting the old file). Whatever I try, I can't seem to pass 'file' to the actionPerformed method, where this should be taking place. Based on responses from other questions about passing arguments to the actionPerformed this is what I tried in an attempt to get this to work:

```
public class Panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    ...
File myFile;


public Panel(File file) throws IOException {

    myFile = file;

     ... 
   }
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             ...
    if (source == exitButton) {

        try (PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(myFile))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < songBox.getItemCount(); i++)
            {
                Song songOut = songList.get(i);
                outFile.println(songOut.getSongName()+ "\t" + songOut.getSongCode()+ "\t" + songOut.getSongArtist()+ "\t"+ songOut.getSongAlbum()+ "\t" + songOut.getSongPrice());
            }
        }
        System.exit(0);

    }
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work. For whatever reason, I get a FileNotFoundException. Are there any better alternatives to passing 'file' to actionPerformed?

Edit: I know it's not the path name or file that is the problem because when the offending code is removed the program imports the file correctly and runs as expected. When debugging the code, myFile does have the correct path so I would think that it should work fine, but it doesn't.

Comment: You haven't shown the source that passes the file to the "Panel". (BTW, it's bad practice to give your classes the same names as Java standard classes, and `Panel` is one).

Comment: How do you instantiate Panel? What's passed to its construction

Comment: I have updated the code to show the entire class that contains the main method to hopefully answer your question

Comment: What is the string path for the file that you're using to instantiate the File object? Is it a relative path or absolute?